# Replace xml document parameters using c#

Tags: c#, xml, replace, tags

I want to replace following @eleval2,@eleval4 parameters with some other values using c#.net.Please help me to do it.

```
<root>
<element1>
    <element2>
        @eleval2
    </element2>
</element1>
<element3>
    <element4>
        <element4>
            @eleval4
        </element4>
    </element4>
</element3>
```

Comment: This xml document can use as a string or a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly updating node:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("file_name.xml"); 
xml.SelectSingleNode("/root/element1/element2").InnerText = "NewValue";
```

For looping:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("path_here");
    XmlNodeList tagNodes= xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("tag_of_your_interest");

    //Loop through first child of above list
    foreach (XmlNode chapter in tagNodes[0].ChildNodes)
    {
             //Perform your updates here 
    }
```

Load from string:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(str);
```

Get all list of nodes matches path:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/sections/notebooks/article");
```

Comment: thank you for your responce.can't we directly replace  the @elementval.in my xml file there can be repeated elements

Comment: so try next snippet added. For looping through children of nodes. Write a recursive function based on this snippet.

Comment: i did it as you said.it was a little bit huge xml with five levels of nodes.it's very time consuming.

Comment: Kindly post your code. if you already know the hierarchical tags then you can use XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/sections/notebooks/article");